# getChildHtml inside a foreach in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm working to a new template in Magento. To avoid duplicate code I want to use the same child template for each product preview.

In particular I've made a showcase like this:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach ($products as $product) {
      $this->getChild('preview_product')->setData('product', $product);
      $this->getChildHtml('preview_product',true); // true to avoid caching
}
```

The block preview_product call the file preview_product.phtml which contain following code:

```
<?php
$product = $this->getData("product");
?>
<h2><?php echo $product->getName(); ?></h2>
```

The problem is simple. The result in this case is the following:

```
<h2>HTC Touch Diamond</h2>
<h2>HTC Touch Diamond</h2>
<h2>HTC Touch Diamond</h2>
```

Same var or same html generated.
How I can use this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo $this->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('core/template')
    ->setTemplate('path/to/template.phtml')
    ->setProduct($product)
    ->toHtml();
```

Comment: The first example generates the same error, second works great! Thanks :)

Comment: This way works, but what about full page cache? It would cache something like this.. how do you exclude it from a FPC when it has no handle for the block

Answer (score 4):

replace the line

```
$this->getChildHtml('preview_product',true);
```

on

```
$this->getChildHtml('preview_product',false);
```

and to prevent build up object each time.